# How does one use LibreOffice FILTERXML function on XML documents with namespaces?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, xml

I'm struggling to get the value of an XML node using the FilterXML() function when the XML document's document element has a namespace specified.

**Example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DocumentElement xmlns="XMLSchemaDefinition.xsd">
    <Field>
        <Value>100</Value>
    </Field>
</DocumentElement>
```

```
= FILTERXML(A1, "/Document/Element/Value[1]")
```

I managed to get FilterXML working by removing the namespace in the following manner:

```
= FILTERXML(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "<DocumentElement xmlns=""XMLSchemaDefinition.xsd"">", "<DocumentElement>"), "/DocumentElement/Field/Value[1]")
```

Is there a way to get the value of the XML node without having to remove the namespace(s)?

I'm currently using LibreOffice Version: 5.0.5.2

Comment: In `<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>` the quotes should be `"` instead of `""`.

Comment: @jim-k Thank you for pointing that out.  I've fixed the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore the namespace like this:

```
= FILTERXML(A1, "/*[name()='DocumentElement']/*[name()='Field']/*[name()='Value'][1]")
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239685/xml-namespace-breaking-my-xpath.

Comment: Thank for the link to "XML namespace breaking my XPath".  I didn't know namespaces could/would create such issues.